# mocking Controller criteria in unit test...grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, junit, criteria

In my controller, i have an action which uses criteria to hit db and fetch results.

```
def c = DomainObj.createCriteria()
def result =[]
result = c.list(params) {
    'eq'("employerid", id)
    }
```

I am trying to mock this criteria in my unit test.

```
def mycriteria =[
list: {Closure cls -> new DomainObj(id:1)}
]                                   ]
DomainObj.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {mycriteria}
```

The above does not work. It throws out an exception when c.list(params) is being executed. The exception is "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testSearch_closure3.docall() is applicable for arguement types:

PS- However, if i remove params from c.list() in controller i.e. see below:

```
def c = DomainObj.createCriteria()
    def result =[]
result = c.list() {
    }
```

then, it is working. Not sure what the problem here is. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the default parametes of the `list` method.

e.g.

```
def method(Object[] params = {/*no params*/}, Closure c, etc. etc.)  {...}
```

above can be used like:

```
method(c: {...})
method(params) {...}
method(params, {...}) // this is the same as the above
method(params:new Object[]{...}, c: {...}) // and this also
//etc.
```

you change `metaClass` and add method `list` that takes only one parameter.

So your `mycriteria` should look like this:

```
def mycriteria = [
    list: {Object params=null, Closure cls -> new DomainObj(id:1)}
    //or recreate `list` declaration with all parameters
]
DomainObj.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {mycriteria}
```

consider this example:

```
def cl = {String a = 'x', b -> println a +','+ b}
cl("z")
```

output is:

```
x, z
```

**EDIT**

To change returned object you do as previously:

```
class A {
}

A.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {
    [list: 
        {def a = new A(); a.metaClass.totalResult=5; a}
    ]
}

def c = A.createCriteria()
def result = c.list()
println result.totalResult
```

Comment: modifying list to     list: {Object params=null, Closure cls -> new DomainObj(id:1)} worked....

Comment: now iam facing another issue. In the controller there is a line result.totalCount where result is the result of the criteria query. But the mocked response in the test has modCount only as it is just a list only. Hence it throws exception at result.totalCount in the controller. Is there any way in which i can set the totalCount in the test?

Comment: @Xeon...still i am not able to mock paged result list in the test case. I am always getting arraylist as the mocked criteria result and that is failing in the controller...i have explained the problem along with code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726279/grails-mocking-criteria-that-returns-pagedresultlist

Comment: thanks xeon..but would be helpful for me if you are able to respond in the new thread...thanks again