# Grails...Mocking criteria that returns PagedResultList

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, junit, criteria

In my controller, i have an action which uses criteria to hit db and fetch results.

```
params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 20, 100)    
def c = DomainObj.createCriteria()
    def result =[]
    result = c.list(params) {
        'eq'("employerid", id)
        }
```

I have mocked this call in my testcase this way:

```
def result=[DomainObj1]         
            def mycriteria =[
                list: {Object params=null,Closure cls -> result}                    
                ]

DomainObj.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {mycriteria}
```

Works fine so far.

But in the controller, there is a line where the code says result.totalCount where result is the output of criteria query and is of PagedResultList type. 
But in the test case, iam mocking the result as an arrayList, but not as PagedResultList. So, code breaks at result.totalCount if run from the test case.

Any idea of how can I mock the criteria response to PagedResultList instead of arraylist so that it has totalCount

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [its interface](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html). You can just compose it like

```
result = new PagedResultList(list: inctanceList, totalCount: inctanceList.size())
```

Comment: What about `[list: inctanceList, totalCount: inctanceList.size()] as PagedResultList` ?

Comment: You can't cast it, the constructor has changed completely in 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails3 you can use Groovy's [`tap`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#tap(groovy.lang.Closure)) closure:

```
PagedResultList<Foo> list = new PagedResultList<Foo>(null).tap {
    totalCount = 23
    resultList = [ foo1, foo2, foo3 ]
}
```